# trying to set data and selected option to select in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model-view-controller

In my application i have select that i bind with options and the user selected saved data on page load.

[Fiddle Link for issue](http://jsfiddle.net/2AwLM/137/)

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="QuestionController">
   <ul ng-repeat="question in Questions">
   <li>
  <div>{{question.Text}}</div>
  <select ng-model="Answers['{{question.Name}}']" ng-options="option for option in question.Options">
  </select>
  <select ng-model="OptSelected" ng-options="option for option in question.Options">

   </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And in my angular controller

```
function QuestionController($scope) {
   $scope.Answers = {};

$scope.Questions = [{ "Text": "Gender?", "Name": "GenderQuestion",
"Options": [{1,"Male"}, {2,"Female"}],
"OptSelected": [{1,"Male"}]},{ "Text": "Favorite color?","Name": "ColorQuestion", 
"Options": [{1,"Red"}, {2, "Blue"}, { 3,"Green"}],"OptSelected": [{ 2, "Blue"}] }];

 angular.forEach($scope.Questions, function(q) {
   var propModel = "Answers['" + q.Name + "']";

   $scope[propModel] = q.OptSelected;
 })
```

In my application I am successful at binding data to select but i canot set the user saved value to select.

I have tried to recreate the issue with fiddle without much success but I think it will provide you all better understanding of what I am trying to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend binding to just the Questions array and avoid the complexity of trying to bind to the corresponding question in an Answers array.  You can always extract what you need from the Questions array either after a selection has been made or all together through some controller level action.

That said, part of your problem is that you don't have a well formed array of objects.

Here's a simplified, working version:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('QuestionController', function($scope) {

  $scope.Questions = [{
    Text: "Gender?",
    Name: "GenderQuestion",
    Options: [{
      id: 1,
      desc: "Male"
    }, {
      id: 2,
      desc: "Female"
    }],
    OptSelected: {
      id: 1,
      desc: "Male"
    }
  }, {
    Text: "Favorite color?",
    Name: "ColorQuestion",
    Options: [{
      id: 1,
      desc: "Red"
    }, {
      id: 2,
      desc: "Blue"
    }, {
      id: 3,
      desc: "Green"
    }],
    OptSelected: {
      id: 2,
      desc: "Blue"
    }
  }];

});
```

```html
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.x" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.11/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.5.11"></script>
</head>

<div ng-controller="QuestionController">
  <ul ng-repeat="question in Questions">
    <li>
      <div>{{question.Text}}</div>
      <select ng-model="question.OptSelected" ng-options="option as option.desc for option in question.Options track by option.id">
      </select>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

</html>
```

Comment: thanks for your answers. I agree i was not quite successful at emulating the issue in my application in fiddle. All i needed was track by. I am new to angular so every step is new discovery.  I saw track by in few example and but did not consider its importance. well all I did was add track by and it working perfectly.Thanks